# gnuplot - change scale of axis

Tags: gnuplot, axis, evenly

I have the following data in `cr.dat`

```
0.03 0.0227352
0.02 0.0276084
0.01 0.0386684
0.009 0.0407197
0.008 0.0431688
0.007 0.04612
0.006 0.0497781
0.005 0.0545085
0.004 0.0608376
0.003 0.069918
0.002 0.0844434
```

And the following plot script

```
set xtics ( 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005, 0.006, 0.007, 0.008, 0.009, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03)
plot "cr.dat" u 1:2 title "cr";
```

Which produces this image
[image: plot cr]

Is it possible to remove the large spaces between 0.01, 0.02 and 0.03?

I hoped the `set xtics` command would plot the given tics evenly along the x axis. But it doesn't.

**Update**

I tried the in [Irregular gnuplot x-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507565/irregular-gnuplot-x-values) suggested solution with `xticlabels` but this produces a strange x and y axis.

The new plot script is

```
set xtics ( 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005, 0.006, 0.007, 0.008, 0.009, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03)
plot "cr.dat" u xticlabels(1):2 title "cr";
```

end the result
[image: plot cr2]

Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Basically `xtics` is doing what you ask him to: displaying tics at the given position. Is an irregular scale what you want?

Comment: I would say yes. I want evenly spaced tics along the x axis.

Comment: Your question is a possible duplicate of [Irregular gnuplot x-values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507565/irregular-gnuplot-x-values)

Comment: @ArcturusB Yes, that question is a possible duplicate. But since the accepted answer is not very clear about which values are used on the x-axis, I'm adding a new answer here, which is hopefully more verbose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get evenly spaced xtics, you must give evenly space x-values. Each of those x-values can be given a custom label taken from the data file using the `xticlabel` function. Note, that this function must always be the last you give in the `using` statement.

In order to get evenly space x-values, use the row number, which is contained in the pseudo-column `0`. So, in order to get the desired plot, use

```
plot 'cr.dat' using 0:2:xticlabel(1) title "cr"
```

That uses the row number as x-value, the values from the second column as y-value, and the value in the first column as xtic label.

If you want the values to be sorted in ascending order, you have several choices:

1. Sort the data file.
2. Sort the data file on the fly (works fine using the Unix command line tool `sort`:

   ```
   plot '< sort cr.dat' using 0:2:xticlabel(1)
   ```
3. Use the negative value of the row number, which effectively gives you a reversed x-axis:

   ```
   plot 'cr.dat' using (-$0):2:xticlabel(1)
   ```

The result of the latter command is

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer. I didn't know you had to sort the gnuplot input data. I always assumed gnuplot would just plot them from start to finish. One never stops learning.

Comment: Gnuplot plots the data according to the given x-value, but in your case the order of the x-values is reversed compared to the row number.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
set logscale x
```

to convert `linear` x-axis to `logarithm` x-axis which will normalize gaps to some extent.

Alternatively, change the size of the plot to get more space

```
set term . . . size 1920, 1080
```

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to mention this but I tried logscale allready. The plot is not really evenly spaced see [here](http://s29.postimg.org/mhw86oblj/test.png)

Comment: @tiom Added plot size alternative