# gnuplot - How do I change xrange when changing x-axis scale?º

Tags: plot, range, gnuplot, axis, xrange

I have the following data:

```
100 100.0
500 499.8
1000 999.0
2000 1994.4
3000 2918.8
10000 8233.8
99999 9433.2
```

I want to plot this so I have all x-axis labels equally spaced. Taking [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31189004/gnuplot-change-scale-of-axis) into account, I made the following script:

```
set terminal png size 500,500

set output 'throughput.png'
set title 'Connection throughput'

plot 'throughput.txt' using 0:2:xticlabel(1) title "Throughput"
```

I get the following.

[image].

Nonetheless, I want the data points from 100 and 99999 values to be visible. To solve it I tried using the `set xrange [0,110000]` instruction. The result this.

[image: this].

As you can see, x-axis is messed up.

My questions are, what is causing this to happen? Is there any other way to set the x-axis range?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data points from 100 and 99999 **are** visible. These violet `+`s are just on top of the axes and hardly visible.

Two possible options:

- change the pointtype and color to make the data points "visible"
- add an offset (or margin) to your graph (check `help offsets`)

Also possible:
`set offsets 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0`

**Script:**

```
### change pointtype and add margins
reset session

$Data <<EOD
100 100.0
500 499.8
1000 999.0
2000 1994.4
3000 2918.8
10000 8233.8
99999 9433.2
EOD

set key top left
set offsets graph 0.05, graph 0.05, graph 0.05, graph 0.00   # left, right, top, bottom

plot $Data u 0:2:xtic(1) w points pt 7 lc "red" ti "Throughput"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]